# Can I package my native-image Java application into a single directory

Tags: java, graalvm, graalvm-native-image

I am planning to use GraalVM's `native-image` tools to package an enterprise application. I've heard that they get packaged into single executable files which would not suit my use case. My application is a pretty large enterprise application which I would like to package into a one-directory application that contains all the `dll`s and the libraries packaged in. I want to package it similar to how in `pyinstaller` we can use the `--onedir` option to package into a single directory. Could anyone please specify clearly how to achieve this because I do not seem to get my answer even after hours of research.

PS: sorry for my bad english (if it was bad)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

GraalVM native image builds a standalone executable or [a shared library](https://www.graalvm.org/reference-manual/native-image/#build-a-shared-library).

I don't know the details on how the `pyinstaller` works. When using GraalVM native image your whole application -- your code, the dependencies, the JDK runtime library classes, the VM components like GC (all of which are in the form of the JVM bytecode) analysed together, initialized, and compiled together.

I don't think you can use GraalVN native image to get separate files, at least right now.